# Want to receive event even if not with focus

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a QGraphicsScene inside a QGraphicView.
I want it to receive my keyboard event even if I didn't press on the screen.
Because if I click anywhere on the screen with a key held I need to do another action, but now I need to click first, so I need to capture the event even if I'm not with the focus on the QGraphicsScene.
I tried to put the event on the MainWindow, but it doesn't work.

I get the event like that:

```
void AreaScene::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
    if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Control){
        MapData::controlPress=true;
    }
}
void AreaScene::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
    if(event->key()==Qt::Key_Control){
            MapData::controlPress=false;
            this->renderArea=false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I implemented it on MainWindow
NOTE: The window dont call this method if the event method is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

in constructor of your QGraphicView subclass:

```
`installEventFilter(this)`
```

and realise this function in class:

```
bool eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent* e);
```

in this function you should code something like

```
switch(e->type())
{
...
case QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonPress:
{
...
}
case QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonRelease:
{
...
}
}
```